# GUI control for representing amount of time

Tags: html, user-interface, user-input, validation

I have an input asking the submitter how long an event took. Right now it's a normal textbox that should error out if anything but an integer is submitted. I tell the submitter to input the length in whole minutes.

However, thinking in minutes isn't the brains best ability... Neither is following instructions, so I often get "support-requests" that state that "my input of 1,5 hours didn't work".

Is there any good way of requesting the user to submit a length of time, and accepting other than minutes in return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why won't you make your control a bit more intelligent and allow this to be entered: `1h`, `40m`, `1.5h`, `1,5h`, `2d5h`, etc. Optionally, you can "AJAXly" parse this value on the server side and provide a side-by-side hint, which will state how exactly your program will interpret the value.

```
                -----------------
Enter Timespan: | 2d1.5h        |   (2 days and 1.5 hours, 25.5 hours total)
                -----------------
```

Additionally, you can use some reasonable defaults, like `1.5` (or `1,5`) is most likely 1.5 hours, not 1.5 minutes, and should be interpreted as such. `0,5` is not 30 seconds as well, but rather 30 minutes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to have a box accepting floating point input and another control to select units. For example

```
Time: [ 4.1     ] [ hours ] <- select units from this drop down box
Time: [ 0.5     ] [ days  ]
Time: [ 1e-3    ] [ years ]
```

Your server code can enumerate the units for generating the control and interpreting the submission.

The explicit mention of the units in the control *right next to the number entry* should help with users not reading instructions — they're probably far more likely to do the right thing if it's there with the data they're entering, than to read every little detail in the fine print a paragraph above it.

(Having said that, I really like Anton Gogolev's answer too. If you can pull it off, do that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can display several input boxes accepting integers, each for a specific unit of time:

```
Time:  [  1 ] day  [  4 ] hours    [ 26 ] minutes   [ 42 ] seconds
```

The user can fill any single box or both.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way, but it doesn't look very pretty, and it seems less user friendly... I need a telepathic interface...